# Running Sidekiq in Rails app using AWS Elasticache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis, sidekiq, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to configure Sidekiq in a Rails 4.1.4 application that connects to an AWS Elasticache Node running Redis.

I set up my Redis server, and followed the directions in this AWS Guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/other-services-redis-cluster.html

And my Redis server was running properly and my app server could connect properly.

I followed these directions to set up Sidekiq to run on the external worker:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

Whenever I visited my app server at the /sidekiq url to view the Sidekiq panel, I kept getting the error on screen saying "Internal Server Error".

My Unicorn error logs do not contain any relevant information, so I am not sure how to get this working.  AWS support did not have any answers either.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is normally seen when assets are not compiled or are not configured to be served from your environment. Start your app/sidekiq in production mode (or whatever environment this is referring to) after changing the production config to point to your local resources (redis+db) and see if the pages are able to load then.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec unicorn
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq -c config/sidekiq.yml
```